# accessing a control from a different class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to access a control in XAML from a different class e.g. a text box called myTextBox. This is what I did but got an error:

```
   Windows1 w = new Windows1();
   w.myTextBox.text = "Hello!";
```

However, I'm getting an error message as:

**'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content' threw
 an exception.**

The sticky error points to

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> <!-- error points to this line -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Please give me some direction to find the reason or error.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Give us the inner exception, please.

Answer (score 1):

Something else is going on, because I was able get this to work in a simple application without doing anything tricky.  So what else is in your scenario? Is your "different" class running in a background thread? If so you may need to use a dispatcher to get to the UI thread.

Comment: I'm trying to access the control in a different class in a method called OnDrop() so when an object is dragged/dropped on canvas I must store its ID in a list and show it in a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://github.com/kaisellgren/Git-GUI/blob/master/Libraries/UIHelper.cs

It will find a Child of a given item in the visual tree.

Usage:

```
var recentCommitMessages = UIHelper.FindChild<ComboBox>(this, "RecentCommitMessages");
```

Here it will search all ComboBox elements for one with id "RecentCommitMessages"

Comment: UIHelper is not recognized. Any idea?

Comment: OK, I included the class and always it returns null.

Comment: sure   `               if (content != null)
                {
                    newObject = new DroppedObject();
                    newObject.Content = content;
                    //get the tag for now
                    Type typeofDroppedOjbect = content.GetType();
                    Object o = t.GetProperty("Tag").GetValue(content, null);
                    newItem.Tag = (string)o;


                   var q  = UIHelper.FindChild<TextBox>(this, "textSearchElement");`

Comment: Did you add the id "textSearchElement" to the textbox element?

Comment: You must name the search element like `x:Name="textSearchElement`, and the first parameter to `FindChild` is the scope where to look for it. You passed `this`, are you sure that's what you want? Is `this` a user control or what is it? Try `UIHelper.FindChild<TextBox>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "textSearchElement")` instead.

Comment: Thanks I got the solution here [one solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722791/find-logical-child-including-hidden-and-collapsed-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

```
w.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { w.myTextBox.text = "Hello!"; }));
```

Comment: as soon as I type it in VS, it says:  **Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type**

Comment: The error still is coming up for both cases of using `Dispatcher.Invoke()`

Comment: Thanks indeed for your comment but before run, VS complains as following: *System.Action does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.*

Comment: Oh, I don't have access to the Visual Studio at the moment. I' sorry. Which version of the .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: You can also use: `w.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) delegate() { w.myTextBox.text = "Hello!"; }));` or `w.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) ({ w.myTextBox.text = "Hello!"; })));`

Comment: I appreciate your concern. I'm using VS2010 and .NET 4.0 platform.

Comment: before I use w.Dispatcher.Method() or anything I am instantiating an object as `window1 w = new window1();`   this throwing error. why is that?!

Comment: I even changed it to  `App.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate() { App.Current.MainWindow.myTextbox.Text = "Hello!"; });`  but myTextbox which is the ID for that control is not recognized.

Comment: Could this be related to some tagging issues in XAML file? because every time error message shows its stick line attached to XAML tag! which is `<Grid.RowDefinitions>`

Comment: Try `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate() { var w = new Window1(); w.myTextBox.Text = "Hello World!"; });`

Comment: This still throws error and points to the XAML file content I had posted above.

Comment: OK the solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722791/find-logical-child-including-hidden-and-collapsed-nodes